# how to run preinstalled windows 7 through ubuntu logged in system with virtual box?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-workstation, virtualbox

i have a pc with dual boot - "windows 7 and ubuntu 10.10". is it possible to run my windows 7 with virtual box or vmware workstation/player through my ubuntu login.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not with VMWare Workstation/Server (which is what I'm assuming you meant, VMWare is a company not a product). Can't speak for VB though. You might be interested to know that Macs running VMWare Fusion *can* do just what you mention.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualBox wiki](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) claims thay yes, you can actually run Windows 7 as a guest operating system. I didn't actually try it, the closest to this is running Windows XP as a guest under FreeBSD.

I'm not sure if you actually meant running your existing dual-booted installation of Win7 under Ubuntu - VirtualBox can't do that as far as I'm aware, but VMWare something-or-other might.